# 18.04: Mouse stops working

Tags: 18.04, mouse, freeze, cursor

First of all, I am new in the community. I have Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS and two accounts (the administrator and the standard user). My problem is that being in the administrator account and (for some reason) I leave my computer to suspend, the mouse stops working when my computer resumes, preventing it from moving the mouse pointer or clicking. It forces me to restart the computer, because I am not able to use my mouse. Can somebody help me?

Comment: Does this also happen in the standard user? Is the mouse a USB connected device or a touchpad (notebook)? Please give more information about your hardware.